# "We couldn't complete the features, Undoing changes" when removing Hyper-V (Windows 10 Pro)

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, hyper-v

I want to remove Hyper-V from computer because it's conflicts with VirtualBox. Problem is when I uncheck Hyper-V option in Windows Features it restarts, works something and then shows:

We couldn't complete the features,
Undoing changes

I uninstalled VirtualBox but still I can not remove Hyper-V. What causing problem?

[Here is logs](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6C73AAB38CB82613!5184&authkey=!AK7zgD0L_F-C5C0&ithint=folder%2C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2016-05-31 20:53:04, Error                 CSI
>   00000140@2016/5/31:18:53:04.634 (F)
>   base\boot\bcd\tools\bcdedit\ai\ **bcdedit**ai.cpp(235): **Error E_INVALIDARG**
>   originated in function Windows::WCP::BcdEdit::BasicInstaller::Install
>   expression: InnerStatus [gle=0x80004005]

the editing of the BCD entry fails and causes the rolback. This can happen if you use other boot loader like GRUB. Temporary disable GRUB, remove Hyper-V and enable GRUB again.

Comment: I don't have GRUB. Just regular Latop (Toshiba L50B) and UEFI boot and Windows 10.

Comment: I recently added SSD to Laptop. Old HDD has C and D partition, I migrated C to SSD. Of course, I removed C from HDD. Now I have Disk 0 with HDD and partition D and Disk 1 with SDD and partitions C and recovery and EFI. Maybe that switching cause problems? But how everything works except removing Hyper-V ?

Comment: ok, this could be the cause. Hyper-V adds an BCD entry to load the Hypervisor at boot, other software doesn't do this.

Comment: Yes. That was problem. After bootrec/bcdboot repair-solution from internet, problem is solved.